# Should i store cookies on the server or on the client

Tags: sql-server, cookies

I realise that cookies are stored on the client side, but what I’m thinking about doing is; instead of storing the actual data in the cookie I just store an ID which matches some id in a ServerSideCookie table in my database(Kinda the same way as sessions)

I wondering pros and cons of doing this.
One obvious pro is that this solution is not limited to 4k of data.
Another pro will be that storing data on the server will be less vulnerable than storing it on the client side.
Third pro is that I do not have to worry about cross browser issues.

Con might be that it is slower, although I have not benchmarked this.

I would greatly appreciate some input.

Thanks in advance, Sigurd.

Comment: You haven't indicated what you hope to achieve by this. With no context it's impossible to say anything much.

Comment: That's not only "kinda" like sessions, it sounds *exactly* like sessions. So why not just use sessions?

Comment: Not in that session expires on,, well, session.

Comment: @MikeW I’m not looking for the best way to solve a problem, but rather pros and cons of storing the cookie data on the server.

Comment: Yes, but a session can be indefinitely long.

Comment: If I where to extend the PHP session lifetime, that means I can no longer use the $_SESSION to store data I actually do want to expire upon the expiration of a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, both are valuable depending on context.

**On the server**

- Advantage: no limit on data
- Minus: size matters when you have a lot of users. for example 1M user x 2k data = 2G data that is sent back and forth over the wire
- Minus: you cannot store info in case you have not an authenticated user

**On the client**

- Advantage: no need to make a trip to the server, you have it locally. it worths for example when you store something related to UI preference of the user (current language, type of view: grid or gallery, etc)
- Minus: you cannot store user sensitive data (e.g. card numbers)